# One-time initialization for NUnit

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

Where should I place code that should only run once (and not once per class)?

An example for this would be a statement that initializes the database connection string. And I only need to run that once and I don't want to place a new method within each "TestFixture" class just to do that.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The `[SetUpFixture]` attribute allows you to run setup and/or teardown code once for all tests under the same namespace.

[Here](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetUpFixture-Attribute) is the documentation on `SetUpFixture`. According to the documentation:

> A SetUpFixture outside of any namespace provides SetUp and TearDown for the entire assembly.

So if you need `SetUp` and `TearDown` for all tests, then just make sure the `SetUpFixture` class is not in a namespace.

Alternatively, you could always define a static class strictly for the purpose of defining “global” test variables.

Comment: According to the [NUnit docs](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setupFixture&r=2.5.5): "A SetUpFixture outside of any namespace provides SetUp and TearDown for the entire assembly." So if you need SetUp and TearDown for all tests, then just make sure the SetUpFixture class is not in a namespace.

Comment: These are the updated docs for the SetupFixture attribute for NUnit 3+: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetUpFixture-Attribute  The big change is that you must use the [OneTimeSetup] and [OneTimeTearDown] attributes on the actual methods, instead of just [SetUp] and [TearDown].

Answer (score 46):

Create a class (I call mine Config) and decorate it with the `[SetUpFixture]` attribute. The `[SetUp]` and `[TearDown]` methods in the class will run once.

```
[SetUpFixture]
public class Config
{
    [SetUp]  // [OneTimeSetUp] for NUnit 3.0 and up; see http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2015/12/upgrading-to-nunit-30-onetimesetup.html
    public void SetUp()
    {
    }

    [TearDown]  // [OneTimeTearDown] for NUnit 3.0 and up
    public void TearDown()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: NUnit v3 changes the attributes slightly. see [v3 docs](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/wiki/SetUpFixture-Attribute)

Answer (score 18):

[NUnit 3](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetUpFixture-Attribute):

```
[SetUpFixture]
public class TestLogging
{
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        DoStuff();
    }
}
```