# NUnit - Using OneTimeSetup And Parameterized TestFixture?

Tags: nunit

I am trying to write Nunit tests that use parameterized TestFixtures but only call `OneTimeSetup` (And `OneTimeTearDown`) once per the entire execution (per parameter, obviously).  I have my tests in separate classes, but the `OneTimeSetup` and `OneTimeTearDown` are being executed once before EACH TestClass.  So, The debug statements for the first param are like this:

```
OneTimeSetUp: parameter: param1
TestClassOneTestOne
TestClassOneTestTwo
OneTimeTearDown: parameter: param1
OneTimeSetUp: parameter: param1
TestClassTwoTestOne
TestClassTwoTestTwo
OneTimeTearDown: parameter: param1
```

But what i want is this:

```
OneTimeSetUp: parameter: param1
TestClassOneTestOne
TestClassOneTestTwo
TestClassTwoTestOne
TestClassTwoTestTwo
OneTimeTearDown: parameter: param1
```

I *think* I can achieve what i want by duplicating each testfixture on each of the test classes, but i will be running **lots** of different tests and I only want to define the multiple parameters once.  Additionally, if I put the OneTimeSetUp and OneTimeTearDown in entirely different namespaces (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3188421/1535349)) I won't be able to access the any global variables in `TestCaseSetup` (such as a webdriver instance) in order to initialize a browser.

Here is my code:

TestCaseSetup.cs

```
namespace NunitTests
{
    [TestFixture("param1")]
    [TestFixture("param2")]
    public class TestCaseSetup
    {
        private readonly string _param;

        public TestCaseSetup(string param)
        {
            _param = param;
        }

        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void OneTimeSetUp()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("OneTimeSetUp: parameter: " + _param)
        }

        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void OneTimeTearDown()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("OneTimeTearDown: parameter: " + _param)
        }
    }
}
```

Tests/TestClassOne.cs

```
namespace NunitTests.Tests
{
    public class TestClassOne : TestCaseSetup
    {
        public TestClassOne(string param) :
            base(param, param)
        { }

        [Test]
        public void TestClassOneTestOne()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("TestClassOneTestOne");
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestClassOneTestTwo()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("TestClassOneTestTwo");
        }
    }
}
```

Tests/TestClassTwo.cs

```
namespace NunitTests.Tests
{
    public class TestClassTwo : TestCaseSetup
    {
        public TestClassTwo(string param) :
            base(param, param)
        { }

        [Test]
        public void TestClassTwoTestOne()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("TestClassTwoTestOne");
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestClassTwoTestTwo()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("TestClassTwoTestTwo");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using a combination of static variables and a `SetUpFixture` with only a `OneTimeTearDown` attribute.  Hopefully this helps others.  I was trying to write selenium tests, so I will include my solution for that as well.

TestFixtureSetup.cs

```
namespace NunitTests
{
    [TestFixture("chrome")]
    [TestFixture("firefox")]
    public class TestFixtureSetup
    {
        public static IWebDriver Driver;
        public static string Browser;

        public TestFixtureSetup(string browser)
        {
            Browser = browser;
        }

        public void SetUpDriver()
        {
            if (Driver != null) return; // Exit method every time except for the first.

            var caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
            caps.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, Browser);
            Driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"),  // Saucelabs URI.  FYI. 
                caps, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600));
        }
    }
}
```

TestFixtureTearDown.cs

```
namespace NunitTests
{
    [SetUpFixture]
    public class TestFixtureTearDown
    {
        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void TearDownDriver()
        {
            // Note that I am calling the static instance of the TestFixtureSetup variables
            if (TestFixtureSetup.Driver == null) return;

            Debug.WriteLine("Browser: " + TestFixtureSetup.Browser);

            TestFixtureSetup.Driver.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Tests/TestClassOne.cs

```
namespace NunitTests.Tests
{
    public class TestClassOne : TestFixtureSetup
    {
        public TestClassOne(string browser) :
            base(browser)
        { }

        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void OneTimeSetUp()
        {
            SetUpDriver()
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestClassOneTestOne()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("TestClassOneTestOne");
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestClassOneTestTwo()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("TestClassOneTestTwo");
        }
    }
}
```

Tests/TestClassTwo.cs

namespace NunitTests.Tests
{
    public class TestClassTwo : TestFixtureSetup
    {
        public TestClassTwo(string browser) :
            base(browser)
        { }

```
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void OneTimeSetUp()
    {
        SetUpDriver()
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestClassTwoTestOne()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("TestClassTwoTestOne");
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestClassTwoTestTwo()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("TestClassTwoTestTwo");
    }
}
```

}