# Correct C# class for multi-threaded writing to a file without any glitches or exceptions

Tags: c#

Using Stackoverflow, I have found various options

- `new FileStream(logFilename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write);` - partial text is written, no exceptions
- `Monitor.TryEnter(fileLock, 2000, ref lockAcquired);` - exceptions
- I have found mention of `ReaderWriterLock` and `ReaderWriterLockSlim`

In 2024, is there a C# class that can handle 6 threads trying to write to 1 file simultaneously?

The situation is 6 NUnit tests running in parallel, all appending their start time and test name to a file

Comment: Write to a file _how_? Append? No, that's not going to happen with multiple threads. IOW, what's your end goal?

Comment: Assume thread 1 writes to the start byte 0 where would you expect thread 5 to write? or any other thread for that matter.

Comment: I was hoping .net could lock and queue and other fancy stuff

Comment: Thinking about options you might be able to write 6 files and then combine them but then it is probably just a slower process to do so since to combine you would have to copy again - like pouring water to 6 jars then pouring them all into one larger one.

Comment: If this is a logging requirement and you want something pre-rolled I'm sure https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-async can do this, in the sense that it will handle queueing.

Comment: .NET can lock and queue and other fancy stuff, but those file stream handles will do exactly what they're supposed to: write a thing to the file at the position they're currently at. If you really do want 5 appending file handles, you'll need to have a shared lock the threads acquire, and within the locked section, the handle will need to seek to the end of the file (as the size will have been changed by another thread), write the thing, then unlock. Or, more simply: use a single writer and a queue.

Comment: On the other hand, if your requirement _isn't_ appending – e.g. 6 threads writing to different places in the same file, I don't see an issue so long as each of them is writing in a different section of the file. But since you're not exactly telling us what your end goal is, we'll have to resort to guessing.

Comment: @AKX We see that he uses Append.

Comment: @Ralf No, that's just one of the various options they have found on SO. It's not telling us what they want to do.

Comment: situation updated in the original question

Comment: Right. Then use a logging library that handles that (Serilog was mentioned upthread), or a single(ton) writer class with a queue.

Comment: "exceptions" doesn't tell us what your code looked like *or* what exceptions you encountered. Do you have requirements that would prevent a simple shared lock with a `File.AppendAllText` call within it?

Comment: the code is copy paste from copilot, for the 'monitor code' the error was 'The process cannot access the file
Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.CreateFile(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options)'

Comment: last time I asked a question it said 'too much code'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In 2024, is there a C# class that can handle 6 threads trying to write to 1 file simultaneously?

No. You could, in theory, use 6 different file streams with `FileShare.Write`, and make sure each thread writes to different parts of the file. But this is probably not applicable to your use case, and you would need to have an in depth understanding of the file system to have much chance of doing this safely.

> The situation is 6 NUnit tests running in parallel, all appending their start time and test name to a file

For this use case you can create a [blocking collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=net-8.0) that all tests post messages to, and use a single thread that uses [GetConsumingEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.getconsumingenumerable?view=net-8.0) to process each message and write them to the file. Just make sure to call `CompleteAdding` and wait for all your messages to be written before finishing your tests. There are also a bunch of other libraries that can provide similar functionality, DataFlow, Channels, etc.

Even better is to just use a logging framework that support asynchronous writes. This will use some type of queuing internally, and since it is actually designed for logging it should be exactly what you need. I'm most familiar with [Nlog](https://nlog-project.org/), where you create a target and specify `async="true"`. But I expect most logging framework to provide similar functionality.

Comment: Is ConcurrentQueue<T> in a singleton the best choice?

Comment: @gords With a plain concurrentQueue you it becomes difficult to read from it safely, thats the reason for the BlockingCollection (that uses a concurrentQueue internally). I dislike singletons on principle, but it might be ok for logging. And I would still recommend a logging framework.

Comment: "There are 4 logging frameworks that pretty much dominate the .NET space. Those are log4net , NLog , Serilog , and Microsoft.Extensions.Logging (only for .NET Core and ASP.NET Core). All of them are great, free, and offer similar functionality."  https://michaelscodingspot.com/logging-in-dotnet/#:~:text=There%20are%204%20logging%20frameworks%20that%20pretty%20much,them%20are%20great%2C%20free%2C%20and%20offer%20similar%20functionality.

Comment: this might be useful to initialise a logger once per run https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188380/one-time-initialization-for-nunit

Comment: A complete logging framework does seem a bit overkill for this requirement though